# Ionic 4 - Link inside innerHTML doesn't work on ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, innerhtml

I want to open link in system browser from html rendered inside innerHTML component.
My code works on browser and on android App but doesn't work on iOS App: it seems that the links are not clickable. Here the code.

PAGE: there's no interesting stuff, i call my API to get html..

TEMPLATE

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item>
   <p [innerHTML]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(article)"></p>
 </ion-item>
..
```

I try this FIX but it doesn't work:

```
  _enableDynamicHyperlinks() {
    setTimeout(() =>
      {
         const urls : any    = this._element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');

         // Iterate through these
         urls.forEach((url) =>
         {
            // Listen for a click event on each hyperlink found
            url.addEventListener('tap', (event) =>
            {
               // Retrieve the href value from the selected hyperlink
               event.preventDefault();
               this._link = event.target.href;

               // Log values to the console and open the link within the InAppBrowser plugin
               console.log('Name is: ' + event.target.innerText);
               console.log('Link is: ' + this._link);
               this._launchInAppBrowser(this._link);
            }, false);
         });
      }, 1000);
  }

     /**
    * Creates/launches an Ionic Native InAppBrowser window to display hyperlink locations within
    * @private
    * @method _launchInAppBrowser
    * @param {string}    link           The URL to visit within the InAppBrowser window
    * @return {none}
    */
   private _launchInAppBrowser(link : string) : void
   {
      let opts : string = "location=yes,clearcache=yes,hidespinner=no"
      this._browser.create(link, '_blank', opts);
   }
```

Comment: Same thing is happening to me on iOS with Ionic v4 using links inside innerHTML. We're using <allow-navigation href="*" /> in our config.xml. Tried a couple different targets (_system, _blank) and still no luck. Android works fine. The only workaround I have is to not use links inside innerHTML, but that adds more code and gets a little uglier.